# How can I write Take(1) in query syntax

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, take

Is it possible to write `IQueryable<MyObject> = query.Take(1)` or something equivalent in LINQ query syntax.  I'm using C# 5 and EF 5.

Comment: Unfortunately no, C# doesn't have as many in-language Linq keywords as VB, but you can do it without it looking too messy by adding `.Skip(n).Take(m)` at the end.

Comment: @TimSchmelter oh cool.  Out of curiosity, what is the syntax in VB.NET?

Comment: `Take` realized the query, it should be keep separate from the logical query.

Comment: @Steaks: `From r In query Take 2` (skip works similar)

Comment: In addition to Take, VB also adds Distinct, Aggregate, Count, Sum as keywords.

Comment: [Query keywords](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310804.aspx) - this might be helpfull

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There is no equivalent to `Take` in the query expression syntax for LINQ in C#. The only methods that have query expression equivalents are

```
Where,
Select,
SelectMany,
Join,
GroupJoin,
OrderBy,
OrderByDescending,
ThenBy,
ThenByDescending,
GroupBy,
Cast
```

This is from §7.16.2 of the specification.

Comment: I didn't know there was an `Enumerable.GroupJoin`!

Answer (score 24):

No. You have to use the dot syntax for that operation.  Same goes for `ToList`, `Count`, etc...

```
var query =
    (from item in list
     where predicate(item)
     select func(item))
    .Take(10);
```