# Is it possible to do all this in a single LINQ query?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, algorithm, linq

I have a function like this

```
private List<Score> getPageNRows ( int N )
{
    // Returns object corresponding to the rows of the table
    // on "page" N of the scores page
    return (from s in this._SD.Scores
            orderby s.score1 descending
            select s)
            .Skip(ScoresController._scoresPerPage * (N - 1))
            .Take(ScoresController._scoresPerPage * N)
            .ToList();
}
```

Where a `Score` is defined by

```
public partial class Score
{
    public Score()
    {
        GameLogs = new HashSet<GameLog>();
    }

    public int id { get; set; }

    [Column("score")]
    public int score1 { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string name { get; set; }

    public DateTime playdate { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<GameLog> GameLogs { get; set; }
}
```

Here, what I really want is a `List<ViewScore>` where `ViewScore` is defined by

```
public class ViewScore
{
    public int score { get; set; } // corresponds directly to score1 in Score class
    public string name { get; set; } // corresponds directly to name in Score
    public string datestr { get; set; } // corresponds to playdate.ToString()
}
```

Is this possible to do all in the LINQ query or do I need to create helper methods?

At the very least, how do I select only the columns `s.score1`, `s.name` and `s.playdate` instead of all of them (via `select`) ?

Comment: @DavidBetz What do you mean by that?

Comment: Nevermind, others (e.g. Arghya C) have said the same thing I said, but as a solid answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do it with `Linq` like this

```
return this._SD.Scores
            .OrderByDescending(s => s.score1)
            .Skip(ScoresController._scoresPerPage * (N - 1))
            .Take(ScoresController._scoresPerPage * N))
            .Select(s => new ViewScore { score = s.score1, name = s.name, datestr = s.playdate.ToString() })
            .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend going with the lambda path:

```
private List<Score> getPageNRows ( int N )
{
    // Returns object corresponding to the rows of the table
    // on "page" N of the scores page
    return this._SD.Scores.OrderByDescending(c => c.score1)
                          .Skip(ScoresController._scoresPerPage * (N - 1))
                          .Take(ScoresController._scoresPerPage * N)
                          .ToList();
}
```

According to MSDN, skip and take are not supported in the query syntax: [See Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386988(v=vs.110).aspx).

And see this [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17890729/how-can-i-write-take1-in-query-syntax) asking a similar thing.

Now if you want to project the `Score` class into your `ViewScore` class, just add a `Select<TSource, TResult>` statement:

```
private List<ViewScore> getPageNRows ( int N )
{
    // Returns object corresponding to the rows of the table
    // on "page" N of the scores page
    return this._SD.Scores.OrderByDescending(c => c.score1)
                          .Skip(ScoresController._scoresPerPage * (N - 1))
                          .Take(ScoresController._scoresPerPage * N)
                          .Select(c => new ViewScore()
                                       {
                                           score = c.score1,
                                           name = c.name,
                                           datestr = c.playdate.ToString()
                                       })
                          .ToList();
}
```

Comment: The name `s` does not exist in the current context

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to return only selected columns using projection. The method `Select()` is used for projetion:

```
return (from s in this._SD.Scores
                orderby s.score1 descending
                select s
                ).Skip(ScoresController._scoresPerPage * (N - 1)
                ).Take(ScoresController._scoresPerPage * N)
                 .Select(x => new ViewScore() { score = x.score1, name = x.name, datestr = x.playdate  })
                 .ToList();
```

Using `Select()` before the query gets materialized with `ToList()` is very handy to limit data returned from DB only to what is really needed.